# Azure Logic App no run failures, thousands of messages in dead-letter

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, dead-letter

I have an azure logic app with 1 workflow that triggers on message in an Azure Service Bus queue
Lock timeout is set to 5 minutes, session not enabled, max delivery attempt set to 100
There are no workflow runs with errors, yet 2 out of 3 messages end up in dead letter with reason max delivery attempts.

How do I go about debugging this?

Edit: Max delivery attempts was only at 10. I increased to 100 and now it is successful. App insights still don't give any information about failures or anything that explains why it even needs more than 1 delivery attempt.
I'm about to give up since it works, but I would really like to know how debug and optimize this.

Comment: Logging of errors maybe? If you expect to get any useful answers you need to put some more effort into asking for it!

Comment: I already do log for errors, but the only errors I have in app insights is unrelated to these (a few with illegal characters in json parse)

Comment: @MariusAgur, I would first start with log analytics and azure monitor. But at this level of information, its hard to say anything. One more thing to consider is that, if you are running into some limit (such as 256 KB limit for standard tier)

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Logic App no run failures, thousands of messages in dead-letter

- I agree with @Ziya Mert Karakas to start with Azure Log Analytics and Azure Monitor.
- This might occur for many reasons, for this I can suggest you to check the logs of service bus, If this does not work check the logs of Azure Logic apps.
- You can enable the session in service bus , as it will be helpful in identifying the problem\the root cause.

[image]

- When I have reproduced in my environment, it was working fine for me by using the same trigger as you have and below is the glimpse of that trigger:

[image]

If still you cannot find the issue, ill suggest you to raise a support request.